# How do you allow a user to add their bulk email address?

Tags: profile, email

Trying to find a way to allow users to indicate which of their email addresses should be used for bulk mailings.

Not seeing an option in profile creation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe bulk email uses whichever address is set to "Primary" if no specific bulk address is specified, and there is an option for primary email in profile creation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, we can set the primary email in a profile. But there's no way to set an email address as the bulk email address.